# Selecting Table and Field based on value of another table

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to join and select a field from a table, where the table and field name are stored as text within another table?

Say I have the tables TableofValues, TableA, TableB and TableC  as below.

Is is possible to join in the relevant table based on TableName in TableofValues, and then select the field based on FieldName, where the TableRowID = ID in the joined table?

This is SQL Server 2008.

Example set of tables:

[image]

Desired Results:

[image]

Comment: Yes, an SQL statement can be dynamically constructed. But, exact help can only be provided if you provide more info about what you are trying to achieve by doing so.

Comment: As @WhirlMind already stated, it will certainly *somehow* be possible in the way you suggested, but maybe you should consider changing your table architecture such that all data is collected in a single table whith an additional column identifying the contents as belonging to 'tableA', 'tableB' or 'tableC'. A layout like this will simplify your data maintenance in the future.

Comment: I second previous statements: repeating 'TableA', 'TableB'... and the column name will take a lot of database space to provide little. I have already seen link tables this way with 'id,table_id,table_row_id,value' that looked similar, and table_id was referring to another table describing the various table (names and columns). However, some application was gathering the information into a single table. Note that I would use a UNION of INNER JOIN instead of the LEFT JOIN (or the INNER JOIN of UNIONs) to keep performance optimal.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this without an dynamic query. See the following code:

```
-- Create Demo Data
CREATE TABLE #TableOfValues(id int identity(1,1), value float, TableName nvarchar(30), FieldName nvarchar(30), TableRowId int)

INSERT INTO #TableOfValues(value, TableName, FieldName, TableRowId)
VALUES  (1234.2,N'TableA',N'Customer',1),
        (245.5,N'TableB',N'Cust',3),
        (248.59,N'TableA',N'Customer',2),
        (8526.36,N'TableC',N'Cstmer',1),
        (224.15,N'TableB',N'Cust',5),
        (148.98,N'TableC',N'Cstmer',2)

CREATE TABLE #TableA(id int identity(1,1), Customer nvarchar(30))

INSERT INTO #TableA(Customer) 
VALUES(N'Bloggs'),(N'Smith'),(N'Jones')

CREATE TABLE #TableB(id int identity(1,1), Cust nvarchar(30))

INSERT INTO #TableB(Cust)
VALUES (N'Aother'),(N'NJONES'), (N'FBLOGGS'), (N'SMITH'), (N'BARTHUR')

CREATE TABLE #TableC(id int identity(1,1), Cstmer nvarchar(30))

INSERT INTO #TableC(Cstmer)
VALUES(N'Mr Fred Bloggs'),(N'Tony Smith')

-- Your Part
SELECT tov.id, tov.value, tov.TableName, tov.FieldName, tov.TableRowId, tabs.tabVal
FROM #TableOfValues as tov
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT N'TableA' as tabName, a.id, a.Customer as tabVal
    FROM #TableA as a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N'TableB' as tabName, b.id, b.Cust as tabVal
    FROM #TableB as b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT N'TableC' as tabName, c.id, c.Cstmer as tabVal
    FROM #TableC as c
) as tabs
    ON tov.TableName = tabs.tabName
    AND tov.TableRowId = tabs.id

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #TableOfValues
DROP TABLE #TableA
DROP TABLE #TableB
DROP TABLE #TableC
```

If you want, you can add (if they won't be present) indices to the tables. Those will further improve the query performance if you seek for specific values.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_TableOfValues_id]
ON #TableOfValues ([id])

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_TableA_id]
ON #TableA ([id])

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_TableB_id]
ON #TableB ([id])

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_TableC_id]
ON #TableC ([id])

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_TableOfValues_TableName]
ON #TableOfValues([TableName])
INCLUDE ([id],[value],[FieldName],[TableRowId])
```

Besides the solution, the table design is kind of bad. It will further improve your `SELECT` performance.

Comment: You can pre filter the rows using a subselect, if needed. I've changed it to a `UNION ALL` construct. It executed in 10 secs. on a complete resultset which holds 6.000.000 rows in the result. Well, I think it's fast enough. :-D
If you filter for a specific TableOfValues value, it will be  instantly there.

Comment: That's why I suggested a bound VIEW, but - probably - the OP will be happy with the pragmatic approach :-)

Comment: I'll currently add some indices to the question (if he's willed to add them). This can be used to push it further. By the way. I share the opinion that the design is bad. But in some cases you just have a structure and need to handle it in any way.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In the projects I'm dealing with there are several generic structures with the same approach. Sometimes there's no way around... My personal favourite is a table valued inline-function for each specific TableName...

Comment: Yes this can also be a solution. Another way would be to split the tables into single tables and use a view for the application. This way your application will work as expected, but the db in the background can work more efficiently. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you should have a VERY GOOD reason for this, 'cause it is VERY BAD design otherwise, you could think of VIEW with SchemaBinding.

You'd have to create a VIEW for any given TableName. This you can use in JOIN

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this. You want to combine all rows from `#TableA`, `#TableB` and `#TableC` and add a column to determine the `FieldName`.

```
SELECT
    Customer = FieldValue,
    Value = v.value
FROM #TableOfValues v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, Customer AS FieldValue, 'Customer' AS FieldName FROM #TableA UNION ALL
    SELECT id, Cust, 'Cust' FROM #TableB UNION ALL
    SELECT id, Cstmer, 'Cst' FROM #TableC
)t
    ON v.FieldName = t.FieldName
    AND v.TableRowId = t.id
```